# how to use vuetify v-rating event?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

in my template i build some v-rating component:

```html
<div class="rating" v-for="rating in applicationViewCv.jobPostRatingFields" :key="rating.id">
    <label :for="rating.id">
      <b>{{rating.field}}</b>
    </label>
    <v-rating
      @input="addRating(Number, rating.id)"
      :value="rating.id"
      background-color="indigo lighten-3"
      color="indigo"
      :dense="true"
      :hover="true"
      size="15"
      :id="rating.id"
    ></v-rating>
  </div>
```

I need to get the selected value in the event and pass it to addRating function. 
now when i log the (Number) it passes to the function it returns:

> ƒ Number() { [native code] }

and if i use `Number()` it always returns zero no matter what i have selected. 
i tied to do this by documentation in the link below:
 https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/ratings

note: i cannot use v-model since the fields i want to get the rating of are dynamic hence i want to add an object for each field and push it into an array and send the array to the server

Comment: where did number come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the user selected rating value from input event, But instead of using Number, you should use

```
@input="addRating($event, rating.id)"
```

> In methods

```
methods: {
    addRating(value, id) {
      console.log(value, id);
    }
  }
```

It prints the selected rating value along with the id

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/xxxPjNv?&editable=true&editors=101